# How to create a .ppk private key file usnig ssh-keygen

Tags: putty, ssh-keys

When I try to create a ssh key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` it creates a public key id_rsa.pub and a private key id_rsa. But this file does not have a .ppk extension. How can we generate a `.pub` and `.ppk` file ? I can also use puttygen but on the puttygen UI where do I put the user email?

Comment: @aaj did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I am on windows so I used puttygen software to generate key pair instead as far as I remember.